# How to Switch from 4G to 3G Galaxy Epic 4G SPH-D710?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 3g, mobile-network, 4g, sprint

I have received Galaxy S2 Epic 4G SPH-D710 unfortunately, 4G connection is not available where I live Just only 3G is available. When I turn on 4G hopefully It maybe switch to 3G automatically I get that "x" below 4G logo in statusbar which means 4G is not available, I couldn't find any option in settings related to 3G. 
Do you have any idea on how to set  3G connection on my phone? 
Is it about installing something so I can get working 3G connection?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

go to your settings and then go to Network Settings and change your network mode to WCDMA/GSM .

Answer (score -1):

It should be automatic and it should show you on the screen what it is using 3G, 4G or H

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This doesn't provide a solution to the problem, as OP clearly states this doesn't work.